# Magento checkout redirect to cart turns me back to product page

Tags: magento, redirect

I have an issue when i go to my cart an then to proceed to checkout it on https does not redirecting me to the same page instead of that it gos bck on product page. Anone have some solution for this issue? Thanks

Comment: check your magento and web server error logs..